# Closing a simplemodal to open a new one

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

what I am trying to do is the following:

1. Close the current open modal
2. Open a new modal

This is proving annoyingly complicated (might be because I am not that much into jQuery and AJAX). I have a login modal and a register modal and currently when you click login you have an option to click "create account" which opens up a new modal. This all works fine but if you close the second modal (the create account one) it closes both modals (login and register) BUT it keeps a tinted and unclickale background as thought it only closed one of them. Is there a way to close the login modal first and then the register? I tried with `$.modal.close()` but that didn't seem to work. The way I did it was this:

```
$(".registerBtnClick").bind('click', function(){
    $.modal.close();
    $("#registerModal").bPopup({
        modalColor: ('#333'), 
        opacity: (.9), 
        closeClass: ('close')
    });
    return false
});
```

Any ideas? (Would be nice if you could be very specific as I, like I said, am not super great with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be the setTimeout in the current close function that is causing the issue. Try the following:

http://jsbin.com/aqavo3/edit

Answer (score 1):

You can't do multiple / nested modals with simplemodal. You should close any open modals before opening a new modal.

If you want to open new modals from existing modals, look at jqModal, not simplemodal.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the close as $('#registerModal').modal.close() and then add onClose callback to .bPopup to open the second one?

Look at the callbacks here for better reference:
http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/